# Last record in HasManyThrough Pivot

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the last record in a pivot table in a HasManyThrough.
There's 4 tables:
Delegate
Location
Status
DelegateLocationStatus

In the DelegateLocationStatus table there are duplicate records for each Delegate, showing the progress of each status. I'm looking to only fetch the last record for the Delegates that have a particular StatusID as their last record in the DLS Table.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
                Delegate::class,
                DelegateLocationStatus::class,
                'fldCID', // Foreign key on the environments table...
                'ID', // Foreign key on the deployments table...
                'ID', // Local key on the projects table...
                'fldUID' // Local key on the environments table...
        );
```

I've tried adding in where clauses like so

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
                Delegate::class,
                DelegateLocationStatus::class,
                'fldCID', // Foreign key on the environments table...
                'ID', // Foreign key on the deployments table...
                'ID', // Local key on the projects table...
                'fldUID' // Local key on the environments table...
        )->where('nm_table_user', function($q) {
            $q->select('fldSTATUSID')
            ->from('nm_tbl_cate_puser_user')
            ->where('fldSTATUSID', '=', 6)
            ->orderBy('ID', 'DESC')
            ->limit(1);
        });
```

But I really can't figure out how to only target the last record in DLS Table where the StatusID is 6.

I hope this makes sense.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use latest('created_at') or latest('updated_at') to select last record added or updated.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
                Delegate::class,
                DelegateLocationStatus::class,
                'fldCID', // Foreign key on the environments table...
                'ID', // Foreign key on the deployments table...
                'ID', // Local key on the projects table...
                'fldUID' // Local key on the environments table...
        )->where('nm_table_user', function($q) {
            $q->select('fldSTATUSID')
            ->from('nm_tbl_cate_puser_user')
            ->where('fldSTATUSID', '=', 6)
            ->latest('created_at')
            ->orderBy('ID', 'DESC')
            ->limit(1);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It’s still bringing back 17 results when it should bring back 16. The second to last result for someone is StatusID of 6, so it should be ignored.